# Assigning CGRect Expression to CGFloat - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, expression, cgfloat

I'm looking to assign below attributes with some values, however having a majorly complex time with the errors I keep getting back.

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]! {
    var padding:CGFloat = 100.0
    rect.size.height = 3              <=1
    rect.origin.y -= padding          <=2
    return self.animator.itemsInRect(rect)
}
```

> 1 = Cannot assign to the result of this expression
>
> 2 = Cannot invoke '-=' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat, @value
>   CGFloat)'

I've tried wrapping the attributes with CGFloat e.g. However with no luck

```
rect.size.height += CGFloat(3*padding);
```

This is a Objective -C version which works fine:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat padding = 100.0;
    rect.size.height += 3*padding;        
    rect.origin.y -= padding;            
    return [_animator itemsInRect:rect];
}
```

How can i swift-ify this code without errors?

Answer (score 4):

Add `var` to your declaration of `rect`. It's currently readonly:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(var rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]! {
```

You could also just create the rect you want:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]! {
    let padding:CGFloat = 100.0
    return self.animator.itemsinRect(CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, 
                                                rect.origin.y - padding,
                                                rect.size.width,
                                                rect.size.height + 3 * padding))
}
```